# Firebase Geofire permission denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm using Firebase Geofire to get user locations to store them in my database. I get an error when I try to run a query:

`Listener at /RDio5CZF2fcJTUOcaeNJhuvYP2Q2 failed: permission_denied
2017-09-19 22:34:24.809 HeartQuest[26419] <Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /RDio5CZF2fcJTUOcaeNJhuvYP2Q2 failed: permission_denied
An error occurred getting the location for "firebase-hq": Optional("Permission Denied")`

The errors occur after running the following query:

```
    let userID = User.current?.key
    let geofireRef = Database.database().reference()
    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
    geoFire?.getLocationForKey(userID!, withCallback: { (location, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("An error occurred getting the location for \"firebase-hq\": \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else if (location != nil) {
            print("Location for \"firebase-hq\" is [\(location?.coordinate.latitude), \(location?.coordinate.longitude)]")
        } else {
            print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"firebase-hq\"")
        }
    })
}
```

Can anyone please explain what the location key is and why I might not have permission for it? I'm using `CLLocationManager` to request the user's permission for their phone's location.

EDIT: Firebase rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".validate": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn" : ["email","username"],
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "data.val() == null || (newData.val() == null && $userId === auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your database's security rules and are you authenticated when querying GeoFire?

Comment: you set Firebase Database security rules ?  read & write -> true ?

Comment: just added the rules, thank you for the replies

Comment: @aofdev updated question

Comment: @winston, Did you figure this out?